# Reopening a stream on a File object

Tags: ruby, io

Say you close a ruby `File` object

```
f = File.open('testfile')
f.close
f.each_byte { ... } #=> IOError: closed stream
```

I know you can reopen the stream through `f = File.open(f)`, but is there a way to reopen the stream through an `IO` method on the object?

e.g.

```
f.close
f.open_again
f.each_byte { ... }
```

Comment: I saw `f.reopen` but it didn't look like what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IO#close` documentation says:

> close → nil
>
> Closes ios and flushes any pending writes to the operating system. The stream is unavailable for any further data operations; an IOError is raised if such an attempt is made.

This means that you cannot reopen the **same** stream again, as it probably has closed the underlying file descriptor also by that time.

What `reopen` gives you, is that you can make this **object** point to another stream/file. Can be useful if your IO object is bound to a constant, but you need to close the file and reopen another.

Comment: Thank you, that explained everything very well. I'll see if I can use `reopen` to my advantage in my project.

Answer (score 0):

`File` superclass `IO` offers [`IO#rewind`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-rewind). This works for persistent resources like files, but not for true streams such as pipes, ttys, and sockets.

Comment: I tried using this after a close and it's giving me a `IOError: closed stream`

Comment: @mcmullins you use `#rewind` _instead of_ `#close` when you want to read the stream again.  If you close it, you're done.

Answer (score 0):

This is what blocks are for!

```
def to_file(&block)
  File.open('/tmp/output_path/to/file', 'w+b') do |file|
    file << 'generate your file content here'
    yield(file) if block_given?
  end
end
```

Now you can pass a block to `#to_file` and perform operations with the file before it's closed for good.

```
FileGenerator.new.to_file do |file|
  # Attach me to an object or whatever you wish!
  # `file` is not closed inside of the block!
end
```